# GCloud API Key - "API restriction" tab disappeared

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-maps-api-2, google-iam

I'm having some trouble with the GCP console, hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

A couple of days ago I generated some API Keys and was able to restrict their validity scope by target API. The form looked like this, and I was able to restrict keys to apply on my GAE private APIs only:

[image]

whereas today the righthand side tab has disappeared on me and I can only apply "Application restrictions" (IP range, referrer, etc..) and I can see merely the following menu.

[image]

I was and still am the owner of the project, and I'm not aware of any change in roles/project config/etc.. (although I can't 100% rule them out)

There is next to zero documentation about the mysterious "API restrictions" tab. Hope someone can help.

Many thanks in advance
F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature has been removed temporarly because was causing issues with the Google Maps API.

API already created making use of these restriction will not work and the workaround is to remove them and recreate them with no restriction.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69715011

Please star the bug to add your vote and subscribe to notifications from Google. Hopefully they will fix the issue soon.

Comment: This - I'm afraid - it's the correct answer.

In my case though, I don't really care about Maps: i want to be able to create multiple keys and restrict their validity to one of my private APIs.
I got N of them in the same project, but they are meant for different audiences and each should come with its own key. The API restriction feature was allowing me to do exactly that.

Any idea for alternatives?

Comment: The only possible workaround I imagine is to create different projects each one with different API, but I guess it will be a lot of work. Post this question on the issuetracker and check the official answer.

Comment: yeah, thought of that but impractical and doesn't scale (there's a cap to the no of projects). I did raise the point in the google forum too: it seems to me they have actually not completely thought through the implications of a quick fix that was affecting maps only - now they got a wider security problem. You would have thought the proper temporary fix was to remove the Maps API from the list of applicable API Restrictions, isolate the problem and don't impact wider functionality...